# req.isAuthenticated() in Google OAuth2.0 using Passport.js is not working when deployed to hosting website but works on localhost

Tags: express, passport.js

I'm creating an application for my school's club to practice questions using express and ejs. For the login I am using google OAuth2.0 with passport. The login works on localhost, it redirects to the landing page after login and they can go to any other pages for example the questions page and everything works as expected. However when I've deployed on digital ocean it randomly asks them to login in again when they try going to other pages. For example the user logs in and is directed to the landing page, then when they click on questions 50% of the time it works and the other 50% it asks them to login in again through the google client and sends them back to the landingpage (callback url). Here is the passport configuration

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
      scope: ['profile', 'email']
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          const newUserProfile = {
            questionsAttempted: 0,
            questionsCorrect: 0,
            questionsWrong: 0,
            pastScores: [],
            wrongQuestions: []
          };

          const newUser = new User({
            googleId: profile.id,
            displayName: profile.displayName,
            email: profile._json.email,
            userProfile: newUserProfile
          });

          await newUser.save();
          return done(null, newUser);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Here is the serialize and the deserialize

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    cb(null, { id: user.googleId, username: user.displayName, email: user.email });
  });
});


passport.deserializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    return cb(null, user);
  });
});
```

Here is the google callback and redirect - > I tried to look throught the passport issues on github and they mentioned to use req.session.save(); however, that did not work.

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  (req, res) => {

      req.session.save(() => {

         res.redirect('/landing-page');
      });
  }
);
```

Here is the landing page template that checks if they are authenticated

```
 try {
app.get("/landing-page", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    res.set(
      'Cache-Control',
      'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stal e=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
    );


    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { ... }} 
    else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.redirect("/")
  }
});
```

Here are the other routes like questions that have the random login issue.

```
app.get("/questions", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {...}
    else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.redirect("/homePage");
  }
})
```